# In the same ASP.Net oauth Web API, How to generate tokens with different expiry dates?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, access-token

I have got a Web API project which uses OAuth. It uses bearer token with the expiry of 20 minutes. I have a specific client that needs to acquire a token which never expires. How can I achieve that? I know that we can not 2 token provider within one Web API. Do I need to have to OAuth server each generate tokens with a specific expiry date?

Comment: It can be possible by add new parameter within the request header that its specifies the user device type. Based on the device type you can set the different expiry dates.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna to create token have no expired, using refreshtoken is the best choice.

you can try using this :

> http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/